# Validate a field depending on another field value in Symfony

Tags: forms, validation, symfony1, field

I have two related fields in a Symfony form: `object_status` and `cryopreservation_method`.

The first one cannot be null and stores one of three possible choices: `liquid`, `solid` or `cryopreserved`.

The second one should be only set if a record has its `object_status` set to `'cryopreserved'`. Otherwise it is `NULL`.

How can I check this in the server side (not with Javascript) before saving the form? I have tried to check for null or empty values in model, but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a conditional validator. This can be done using a **sfValidatorCallback** (easier than creating a new validator). Check [this example](http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/conditional-validator) of the Symfony Cookbook (is for 1.2 but works in 1.4).