# Symfony form framework: validate form fields depending on the others fileds value

Tags: forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate a field depending on another field value in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441982/validate-a-field-depending-on-another-field-value-in-symfony)

How can I unset, ie, some form fields named A e B when a radio button R is checked? 
I'd want to normally configure validators to these A/B fields but skip the check of their validators (and unset their value) if the radio button R is checked (eg, set A and B as strings required but validate them when R is checked even if they are empty).

I tried to override doBind function, use pre/post validator but I continue to receive 'required' message

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441982/validate-a-field-depending-on-another-field-value-in-symfony) ?

Comment: I did. If I use post validator to throw an exception, validation works right. But in this case I'm trying to unset values and do pass the validation of a field that normally is set as required. Is this a correct operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a correct operation. I found a [couple](http://blog.barros.ws/2008/11/05/conditional-validator-in-symfony-another-approach/) of [answers](http://blog.rajatpandit.com/2009/02/22/conditional-validator-in-symfony/) and the best place to do that is to override the `bind` function and redefine validator's options depending on values from the form (to disabled required option or remove the validator) :

```php
public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null)
{
  if($taintedValues["method"] == 'phone')
  {
    // disabled required
    $this->validatorSchema["email"]->setOption('required', false);
  }
  else
  {
    // remove the validator
    $this->validatorSchema['other_field'] = new sfValidatorPass();

    // and disabled required
    $this->validatorSchema["phone"]->setOption('required', false);
  }

  return parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);
}
```

Comment: I've searched for several hours without finding any solution..
But, as for  doBind method, if I don't call `bind` explicitly it isn't called. Is there a reason? It should be called..

Comment: You *should* explicity call `bind` function to validate your form (ie: in your action), [see this doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/10-Forms#chapter_10_sub_form_handling_with_data_validation).

Comment: It's true, the bind of main form A is called in action. In this way the form A and each subforms B and C are validated. 
But now I'm trying what is said above, so in the subform B I override the function `bind`. In this situation I thought `bind` is automatically called again (but using the override one) but it doesn't happen. However, also calling `B->bind` explicitly into the `A->doBind` the problem isn't resolved. My `B->bind` function is built as in your example having only added the unset to the values.
And then, which is the difference between doBind and bind?
Thank you for your help

Comment: `doBind` is called inside `bind`. That's all. So it seems that sth inside `bind` function failed and don't call the `doBind` function.

Comment: I tried in every way: I created that function, call `bind` in A::doBind or in A:bind and function is called but the validation still failing. Maybe I forgot to say that this B form is a form embedded in A. In fact doBind also validate B form. I also followed this solution to implement what I need [link](http://di-side.com/di-side/services/web-solutions/symfony-embedrelation-many-to-many-doctrine-relations/) but it doesn't work too.